# Deploying React + API apps on two different hosts

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, production-environment

I'm trying to figure out what are the best practices to deploy a React app that consumes an API on a different host in *production*.

Currently in DEV I have the following:

**frontend** - React app running on webpack server: `http://localhost:3000/`

**backend** - API (django-rest) running on: `http://localhost:7000/`

Right now I define the API url in `package.json` proxy attribute: `"proxy": "http://localhost:7000/",` and I make API calls using Axios to `api/something/something/` etc.

**Both apps are standalone with separate repos and I'd like to keep it that way** (I don't want to merge both apps into a single codebase.)

My question:

**What is the best way to configure React in production to consume the production URL?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use process.env.NODE_ENV to find out the current environment and assign the proper url to your base url constant.
In development, you will get process.env.NODE_ENV as "development" and in production, you will get process.env.NODE_ENV as "production".

Comment: Where do I define that base URL constant in production?

Comment: I mean, I understand that I would need to set it as a .env variable, but is there a location where the app would 'know' to look for the base URL in production (like 'proxy' in dev)?

Comment: Create a config file that exports different values depending on the environment.

Comment: Do you have a constant.js file?